# MVVM passing control handle to the model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

In my model I am using an external .dll file that needs handle to the UI control in order to display some images on it. I guess .dll related logic belongs to the model - not the UI.

I have a View. Inside this view I've got:

```
    <WindowsFormsHost x:Name="winformsHost" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,0,5,0"/>
```

Now, in my model I need the handle to the control that will be placed in this WindowsFromsHost. So what I am doing is I am passing a reference to the Windows FormsHost to the ViewModel:

```
    //View
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel(this.winformsHost);
    }
```

Then in the ViewModel, I am passing it to the Model:

```
    public MainWindowViewModel (WindowsFormsHost containerForRenderPanel)
    {
        model = new Model (containerForRenderPanel);
    }
```

Finally in the model, I am creating a new control and now I have access to its handle from within the model:

```
public class Model : BindableBase
{
    private WindowsFormsHost renderPanelContainer;

    public WindowsFormsHost RenderPanelContainer
    {
        get { return renderPanelContainer; }
        set { SetProperty(ref renderPanelContainer, value); }
    }

    public Model(WindowsFormsHost container)
    {
        RenderPanelContainer = container;
        RenderPanelContainer.Child = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();   
    }
}
```

**I know that this approach violates the MVVM pattern. How can I pass the handle from the View's control to my model?**

Comment: Why should the model be doing UI related work ? Keep that work in the view ?

Comment: In my model, I am using an external .dll file that needs the handle to an UI control to display some things directly on this control.

Comment: You can provide a way to pass that info, e.g. when View is created some method of VM is called (which in turn calls Model method).

Comment: Would you mind providing me with some example that I could relate to? I'm quite new to the WPF and MVVM pattern. As far as I understood, if "some VM method is called" then the VM will need reference to the view, to read the control's handle and pass it to model. It is also a bad thing.

Comment: Generally, it goes against MVVM to have the model aware of the UI, but in your case, it doesn't sound like there is any way to avoid it.  My general solution to this is to put a public property on the VM, and have some code in the UI's Code Behind update the property in the `DataContextChanged` event of the window (or whatever is actually bound to the VM) with a reference to the actual control you need.

Comment: *passing control handle to the model* that isn't MVVM, so whatever works do it.

Answer (score 0):

Create Observable Collection of object type Panel. Bind that collection to Yours WindowsFormsHost child element.

Comment: So in ViewModel I will create an Observable Collection of Type Panel. When creating the Model, it can return handle to the Panel (Panel will be created inside the model). Then this handle will be put in the ObservableCollection<Panel> created in the VM. Lastly, the View will bind the WinfowsFormsHost to the ObservableCollection<Panel>. Is this a fully valid  MVVM approach?